# Find the ratio $p:q:r$, if $p,q,r$ are in H.P, and their squares are in A.P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

> If three unequal numbers $p,q,r$ are in H.P and their squares are in A.P, then find the ratio $p:q:r$
>   .

**Attempt**

A.P(1): $\dfrac{1}{p},\dfrac{1}{q},\dfrac{1}{r}$

$$
\dfrac{1}{q}-\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{q}\implies\dfrac{p+r}{pr}=\dfrac{2}{q}\\
$$

A.P(2): $p^2,q^2,r^2$

$$ q^2-p^2=r^2-q^2\implies p^2+r^2=2q^2\\
$$
As this was asked as a multiple choice question i was wondering what is the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @user58697 what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ q= \frac{2pr}{p+r} $

$ 2pr=q(p+r) $.......(1)

$ p^2, q^2, r^2 $ are in AP thus

$ (p+r)^2 -2pr=2q^2 $

$ (p+r)^2 -(p+r)q=2q^2 $.......(2)

Solve using quadratic equation.

You will get two cases, one will be $ p + r = -q $ and other will be $ p + r = 2q $

Solve each case with equation (1) and (2).

Reject  $ p + r = 2q $.

Solving  $ p + r = -q $ and (1) and (2) you will get $ p - r = \pm \sqrt3 q $. Now solving this with $ p + r = -q $ you will get relation between $ p,q,r $. Solving this you will get the ratio.

Will you take it from here?? Or should I solve it further?

Answer (score 0):

Start with your
$\dfrac{1}{q}-\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{q}\implies\dfrac{p+r}{pr}=\dfrac{2}{q}\\
q^2-p^2=r^2-q^2\implies p^2+r^2=2q^2\\
$

Then
$q= \dfrac{2pr}{p+r}$.

Putting this to the second equation,
$p^2+r^2
= 2(\dfrac{2pr}{p+r})^2
=\dfrac{8p^2r^2}{(p+r)^2}
$
or
$(p^2+r^2)(p+r)^2
=8p^2r^2
$.
Dividing by $r^4$
and letting
$x = p/r$,
$(1+x^2)(1+x)^2
=8x^2$.

With the help of Wolfy,
this is
$0 = (1-x)^2(x^2+4x+1)
$
so
$x = 1$
or
$x
=\dfrac{-4\pm\sqrt{12}}{2}
=-2\pm \sqrt{3}
$.

If $x=1$ then
$p = r = q$.

If $x = -2+\sqrt{3}$,
$p = r(-2+\sqrt{3})$
so

$\begin{array}\\
q
&=\dfrac{2r^2(-2+\sqrt{3})}{r+r(-2+\sqrt{3})}\\
&=r\dfrac{2(-2+\sqrt{3})}{-1+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=r(1+\sqrt{3})(-2+\sqrt{3})
\qquad\text{since }(-1+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})=2\\
&=r(1-\sqrt{3})\\
\end{array}
$

If $x = -2-\sqrt{3}$,
$p = r(-2-\sqrt{3})$
so

$\begin{array}\\
q
&=\dfrac{2r^2(-2-\sqrt{3})}{r+r(-2-\sqrt{3})}\\
&=r\dfrac{2(-2-\sqrt{3})}{-1-\sqrt{3}}\\
&=-r\dfrac{2(-2-\sqrt{3})}{1+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=-r(-1+\sqrt{3})(-2-\sqrt{3})
\qquad\text{since }(-1+\sqrt{3})(1+\sqrt{3})=2\\
&=r(-1+\sqrt{3})(2+\sqrt{3})\\
&=r(1+\sqrt{3})\\
\end{array}
$

Check (with $r = 1$)
with $x = -2+\sqrt{3}$.

$p+r = -1+\sqrt{3}
$
and
$pr =-2+\sqrt{3}
$
so
$2pr  =-4+2\sqrt{3}
$
and
$q(p+r)
=(1-\sqrt{3})(-1+\sqrt{3})
=-4+2\sqrt{3}
$
and
$q^2 = 4-2\sqrt{3}$
and
$p^2+r^2
=1+(-2+\sqrt{3})^2
=1+7-4\sqrt{3}
=8-4\sqrt{3}
$.

It also checks for
 $x = -2-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: What is wolphy?

Comment: What I call wolfram alpha.

Comment: You don't need to use wolphy, that equation can be solved by standard process of solving a cubic equation. Using hit and try find 1 is a factor thus (x-1) is factor from remainder theorem. Diving x-1 and the equation gives a result. Again repeat the process in the result.

Comment: I know. I was being lazy.

Comment: I think you should at least mention the method(which I described above) in your answer. Last thing we want is that students saying " how am I suppose to know that? Math looks so much like magic". The reason I am making this comment is because I used to(and sometimes still do) feel like that student. @martyCohen

Comment: For this one, the rational root theorem would suggest $x=1$. Dividing by this would again suggest $x=1$. This leads to a quadratic.